# How do you list of the options of a Leiningen template?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, luminus

From the [Luminus documentation](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs) I see there's an option called h2 when creating a Luminus app:

```
lein new luminus guestbook +h2
```

How can I see all the available options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it seems passing a wrong attribute was all that was required, at least in case of luminus, to get the list of attributes:

```
$ lein new luminus meh +meh
Unrecognized options: +mhe
Supported options are: +immutant, +site, +h2, +dailycred, +cljs, +sassc, +swagger, +auth, +http-kit, +cucumber, +aleph, +mongodb, +postgres, +mysql
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following command:

```
lein new :show <template>
```

Unfortunately in case the template function doesn't provide doc string and uses rest args or options map you won't get much from it and probably need to check the sources of the template.

Check the whole help for `new` task with `lein help new`.